# How to access related objects after using statement has finished in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use the EF 3.5 in VS 2010. I have a method which returns a struct. In the struct there is an object armatuur. When the struct is returned i want to access the related objects from the armatuur instance.

However

the method returning the struct:

```
public LampPostDetail getLamppostInfo(int id)
{
    LampPostDetail lpd;

    lpd.xPos = 0;
    lpd.ypos = 0;
    lpd.armatuur = new Armatuur();

    //get the info from object
    using (var db = new OvisionDBEntities())
    {
        var objects = from o in db.Objects
                      where o.ObjectId == id
                      select o;

        foreach (OVSL.Data.Object o in objects)
        {
            lpd.xPos = o.XCoordinatie;
            lpd.ypos = o.YCoordinatie;
            lpd.armatuur = o.Armatuur; //which is a table in my db
        }

        return lpd;
    }
}
```

struct:

```
public struct LampPostDetail
{
    #region [ Data Members (14)]
    //lamppost info
    public double? xPos;
    public double? ypos;

    //a lamppost can have several armaturen
    public OVSL.Data.Armatuur armatuur; //is a table in my db

    #endregion [ Data Members ]
}
```

when doing this in my client:

```
 LampPostDetail lpd = client.getLamppostInfo(id);
 string brand = lpd.armatuur.producer.name; //producer is related object of armatuur
```

I get a ObjectDisposedException. I understand that this happens because the LampPostDetail object is disposed after the using block is finished. But how do i get this to work? Retrieving all information I need (like brand name e.g.) before I return it to the client is not not an option.

Comment: What line exactly is throwing the exception?  I get that it's in your client but it's difficult to tell precisely which line is the issue.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the getLamppostInfo method ?

Comment: @yyy, its the line in which producer is asked. Yes i can edit the method.

Comment: @user957902 Just pinging you because the OP answered your question at the same time he pinged me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that gets disposed here is the `OvisionDBEntities` context. After that, no lazy loading is possible. How to deal with that? In fact your question is: what can you do to feed a client with all data that are potentially required for user actions at any time? I see three or four options:

1. The standard way to enable access to navigation properties of entities after context disposal is calling [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.include%28v=vs.103%29.aspx): `from o in db.Objects.Include("Armatuur.Producer")...` But that's clearly not an option for you.
2. Let the context live and rely on lazy loading to fetch data on demand. This may be an option for you. But long-lived contexts may cause problems like gradually declining performance as the internal change track record grows, and stale cached data giving rise to refresh/reload statements scattered all over the place.
3. In stead of navigation properties/lazy loading fetch data on demand from a service/repository layer that uses context instances per call. I think this option could work well for you.
4. More a functional than a technical option: design use cases that can do with less data (so that `Include` may suffice after all). No one can take in a grid with thousands of rows and tens of columns. Well-designed user interaction can drastically reduce the amount of data that is pumped into a client (and I'm only at the beginning of getting this).

Comment: option 4 required the least change in code, went for that. UI design should indeed preoccur  to development ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its not you LampPostDetail that is getting disposed, it is the Armatuur object you retrieved from the database that it references, or an object that Armatuur is referencing.

I can see two options to getting around this. The first is to make the Entity context an optional parameter to your getLamppostInfo info method. Since you are using 3.5 you will have to do an overload to keep the orignal functionality:

```
public LampPostDetail getLamppostInfo(int id,OvisionDBEntities context)
{
...
    try
    {
       OvisionDBEntities db;
       if (context == null)
          db = new OvisionDBEntities();
       else
          db = context;
    ...
    }
    finally
    {
       if (context == null && db != null)
         db.Dispose() // or close maybe
    }

    retun lpd;

 }

 // Overloaded function to keep orignal functionality (C# 3.5 does not have 
 // optional parameters)
 public LampPostDetail getLamppostInfo(int id)
 {
     return LampPostDetail(id,null)
 }
```

Now you can call it as:

```
using (var db = new OvisionDBEntities())
{
   LampPostDetail lpd = client.getLamppostInfo(id,db);
   string brand = lpd.armatuur.producer.name;
}
```

And your objects will still exist when you try to reference them.

The other option is to detach your referenced objects from the entity context, before disposing of it.

```
  db.Detach(o.Armatuur);
```

However, I don't believe that detaches any objects references by that object. So you would have to interate the reference trees and detach thoes objects as well.

Comment: Ugh! What has happened to the formatting? All of my indents are gone!

Comment: alright thanks for your time, i'll try it out tommorrow at work, i'll let you know!